# ios Cordova javascript focus event never comes

Tags: javascript, ios, gwt, cordova

Developing iOS application with GWT 2.5.1 and Cordova 2.9.0.0.

Met quite a big issue: upon tapping any text box virtual keyboard appears but no javascript focus event is fired (or any other events except window resize).

So i cannot determine which text box was tapped. Moreover i cannot even tell why window size has changed - because of screen orientation change or keyboard appearance.

document.activeElement points to BODY element.

The second tap (when the keyboard is visible) does fire onFocus event.

Tried on iphone simulators 5.0 and 6.0

So the question is how can i get active text box on the first tap or check if virtual keyboard is visible (without writing phonegap plugin)?

Update:
the issue happens only when config.xml has KeyboardShrinksView=true

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as far as i understand, this issue takes place cause of peculiarity of focus event handling in iOS webview (something related to ghost click event. didn't have time to dig deeper).

The solution is to catch "touch" event with jQuery and set focus to tapped input manually.
I'm not sure why we need jquery here but it is the only way i managed to catch "touch" event

The code (used GWT jQuery port gwtquery):

```
$("input").live(Event.ONTOUCHEND, new Function() {
@Override
public boolean f(final Event e) {
    $(e).focus();
    return false;
   }
});
```

so far it works more or less well.